# Undefined variable after upgrade to PHP 5.4

Tags: php, php-5.4

I couldn't figure out what's wrong with this simple code:

```
<?php    
$arr[0]['name'] = 'foo';    
?>

<? foreach ($arr as $v): ?>    
    <?=$v['name']?>    
<? endforeach; ?>
```

This returns:

`Notice: Undefined variable: v`

Anyone knows what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the raw script output (not the browser rendering). Most likely, you haven't enabled short tags and your `foreach` block is not even running.

Related: [PHP tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<?php    
$arr[0]['name'] = 'foo';    
?>

<?php foreach ($arr as $v): ?>    
    <?=$v['name']?>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I agree that the answer could merit an explanation but switching to long tags is a valid fix.

Comment: Voting down is for 'wrong' answers. Please be considerate about down voting.

Comment: O/P asked 'What is wrong with this?' So I corrected the code work.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a multidimensional array.

There is a zero index prior to the name index.  Use a key=>value in the foreach.

```
<?php    
$arr[0]['name'] = 'foo';    
?>

<?php foreach ($arr as $v=>$i): ?>    
    <?php echo $i['name']; ?>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's issue at all. There is nothing wrong with the `foreach` block in the question (aside from its surrounding short-tags).

Answer (score -1):

Never Use `<?` as its deprecated you should use `<?php` well in case of `<?=` it will work because its an short hand method.
so you should use:

```
<?php    
$arr[0]['name'] = 'foo';    
?>

<?php foreach ($arr as $v): ?>    
    <?=$v['name']?>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can Someone Please Specify the reason for down-votes ?

Comment: I didn't down-vote you but it's probably because short tags is not really deprecated?